# Drupal Services returns javascript after results

Tags: services, 8

I am using Services Views and have a view that returns the json array, plus a script tag (the default `jQuery.extend(Drupal obj...)`. I do not want this `jQuery.extend` script to be added for a services response (obviously!) and I don't know how it got here.

The endpoint url is api/events. The view Services display has a path of event. nid is an explosed filter. The view works, I get the right json, but then I have this  tag at the end.

Anyone seen this before?

Here's an example:
http://www.mysite.com:8082/api/events/event?nid=9

Result:
**[{"nid":"9"}]**

```
<script type="text/javascript"&gt;jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"thmr_2":{"id":"thmr_2", "name":"textfield", "used":"theme_textfield", "type":"func", "duration":0.17, "candidates":[ "catholicfoundation_textfield" ], "preprocessors":[  ], "processors":[  ]}, "thmr_3":{"id":"thmr_3", "name":"form_element", "used":"theme_form_element", "type":"func", "duration":0.07, "candidates":[ "catholicfoundation_form_element" ], "preprocessors":[  ], "processors":[  ]}, "thmr_4":{"id":"thmr_4", "name":"button", "used":"theme_button", "type":"func", "duration":0.08, "candidates":[ "catholicfoundation_button" ], "preprocessors":[  ], "processors":[  ]}, "thmr_1":{"id":"thmr_1", "name":"views-exposed-form.tpl.php", "used":"sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fcontrib\u002Fviews\u002Ftheme\u002Fviews-exposed-form.tpl.php", "type":"tpl", "duration":7.42, "candidates":[ "views-exposed-form.tpl.php" ], "preprocessors":[ "template_preprocess", "template_preprocess_views_exposed_form", "contextual_preprocess" ], "processors":[ "template_process", "rdf_process" ]}, "thmr_5":{"id":"thmr_5", "name":"form", "used":"theme_form", "type":"func", "duration":0.08, "candidates":[ "catholicfoundation_form" ], "preprocessors":[  ], "processors":[  ]}, "request_id":"13390714085122a99db5036", "devel_themer_uri":"\u002Fdevel_themer\u002Fvariables\u002F13390714085122a99db5036"});</script>
```

Comment: could be a complication with the devel_themer module - have you tried the above with the devel_themer module turned off?

Comment: That was it! Thanks schnippy. Hope that helps someone.